# Thoughts on variable/function naming conventions

Tags: coding-style

I've been coding on and off my whole life. I've mostly coded Perl, but also some Java, PHP, C, C++. I've even took a stab at Emacs Lisp, and I've done the occasional shell script. However, I've never actually engaged the subject to gain any kind of expertise – other things have had higher priorities for me. I don't consider myself to be really proficient in any language but Perl, and also now Haskell which I'm taking a course in right now.

Lately, I've been thinking about my style of coding. Not the style of the actual code; as a CS student I only do projects for fun or for school, which enables me to write what in my opinion is beautiful code almost always. One question in particular has been troubling me. It's a rather curious thing, but still something I would like to hear other opinions about.

Here's the thing: I find myself taking a fair amount of time to name my functions and variables to the most easily understood names I can possibly think of. Sometimes this task can be very tedious, even when not taking into account the difficulty of finding a variable name that conveys the meaning of a piece of code.  For example, right now I'm making a function that looks like this.

This is Haskell code but the meaning should be quite clear. (It's exact meaning isn't that important so if you want to, just skip the code and read on.)

```
-- return the row with least number of Nothing values
bestRow :: [[Maybe Int]] -> Int -> Maybe (Int,Int)
bestRow [] _ = Nothing
bestRow (row:rows) thisIndex
   | nextRow == Nothing && thisFilled > 8 = Nothing
   | nextRow == Nothing       = Just (thisIndex,thisFilled)
   | thisFilled >= nextFilled = Just (thisIndex,thisFilled)
   | thisFilled <  nextFilled = nextRow
     where thisFilled             = length $ filter (/= Nothing) row
           nextRow                = bestRow rows (thisIndex + 1)
           (nextIndex,nextFilled) = fromMaybe (-1,-1) nextRow
```

I couldn't decide on the variable names. The function did it's task well but it wasn't as clear as it could be. Once I settled on a solution, I spent 15 minutes on naming and renaming the variables.  Should I go with curIndex, nextIndex || index, nextIndex || ind, indN etc? 15 minutes after I decided I was done, I realized this function wasn't needed after all: I found a much better solution to my problem. BOOM I had lost a lot of time simply cleaning code to no use to anyone, least of all to me. Or at least it felt that way.

This is something which has happened to me more than once, and is quite frustrating, mostly because it makes me feel dumb. What are your thoughts on this subject? Is this something you've experienced, something wrong with my way of doing things or simply something unavoidable?

Are there "perfect" variable names, or is it "ok" if they at least doesn't obfuscate your code?

Thanks,

Stefan Kangas

Comment: You probably lose less time cleaning up bad code then throwing it away than not cleaning it up and keeping it. I wish the people I work with worried about variable naming as much as you do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the book Clean Code by Robert C. Martin

One thing he goes into detail on is naming.  Variable and function names should be as exact as possible.  If you require a comment to describe it, the function is either doing too much, or the name can be clearer.

The goal, is to have code that reads like a story.  Changing variable and function names and breaking them down into several functions or variables if necessary to achieve this goal.

Great book, worth every penny

Comment: +1 - variable and function names should be comments in and of themselves. That said, there are some meaningless but well-established naming practices (like `i`,`j`,`k` for control loop) that are best followed simply because everyone in the field expects things to be named that way already.

Comment: In general, again, from the book, the shorter the scope of a variable, the shorter it's name can be.  Hence, control variables in a loop can be 1 character...and it's a well established practice, it's what's expected.

Answer (score 0):

Good names for variables and functions make understandable code.  Good names should describe the intent and use of a variable or function.  Bad names confuse other coders when it comes time to make changes.

Clarity is good in code.

Answer (score 0):

I think its psychological, I always used to think my variables etc was unreadable to anyone but me  even though I always placed comments in my code.

Whenever I had to go through code by someone else I was quite surprised at how I could easily read their code without having to read every single comment, the exact same thing happens when they read my code so clearly I'm doing a good job ;)

I think as long as your comments are meaningful and actually describe what a method does, what a variable is being used for you should be fine.

One tip is to always make sure your comments are up to date. I've seen code too many times where the comments for a method haven't changed, but the method code has.....it can be very confusing!

Comment: But if your variables have descriptive names beforehand, those comments are unnecessary.

For example.  If you see a variable named "email", what is it?  Is it a persons email address?  Or is it a boolean indicating whether they want to receive email?  Or a boolean indicating whether they have an email address.  Had it been named hasEmail or emailAddress, we'd be more sure.  Even if you had a comment, I really don't want to scroll up to the definition to find the answer.